# Como tornar os icones _dt responsivo

Tags: php

Estou com esse código abaixo funcionando em quase todas as funções.

A unica coisa que falta para ficar 100%, é torna-lo responsivo.

Ou pelo menos reduzir o tamanho de cada ícone de acordo com as dimensões dos dispositivos.

Já tentei de varias formas, mas sem sucesso.

Se os amigos puderem me dar uma dica ou mesmo me orientar o que devo fazer para conseguir meu objetivo, ficarei agradecido.

Abaixo o Código:

```
        <div style="max-width:30px; width:100%;" class="social_bar">
        <style>
        .social{
            display:block;
            width:30px;
            height:30px;
            background-image: url(img/Preta.png);
            float:left;
            margin-left:4px;
            overflow:hidden;
            text-indent:-999px;
            margin-bottom:4px;
        }

        .social_bar{
            margin-top:-100px;
            position:fixed;
            right: 7px;
            top: 50%;
            width:40px;
            z-index:9999;
            float:left;
        }

        #contato_dt{ background-position: 0 0;} 
        #instagram_dt{ background-position:-32px 0;}    
        #facebook_dt{ background-position:-64px 0;}
        #twitter_dt{ background-position:-96px 0;} 
        #youtube_dt{ background-position:-128px 0;} 
        </style>

        <a href="#" id="contato_dt" class="social" title="Contato Via E-mail"></a>
        <a target="_blank" href="#" id="instagram_dt" class="social" title="Acesso ao Instagram"></a>
        <a target="_blank" href="#" id="facebook_dt" class="social" title="Acesso ao Facebook"></a>
        <a target="_blank" href="#" id="twitter_dt" class="social" title="Acesso ao Twitter"></a>
        <a target="_blank" href="#" id="youtube_dt" class="social" title="Acesso ao Youtube"></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Descobri que esse meta `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`, que uso para responsiva as fontes que esta impedindo o responsiva dos ícones. Alguém saberia me dizer o porque e qual seria a solução? Abraços.

Comment: Olá, Não percebi o objetivo. Responsivo como assim? Qual regra que pretende? Acho o que pretende é mais css ou javascript/jquery e não php